# Unique set of basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am interested in finding conditions for a unique set of basis vectors in a finite dimensional vector space.

Consider some finite dimensional vector space. Then there is an infinite number of sets of vectors that form a basis. If I now restrict the vectors to be orthogonal then I reduce the number of sets of vectors that form a basis but there are still infinitely many. If I further restrict each basis vector to have norm $1$ then I further restrict the number of sets of basis vectors. Can I include further restrictions that eventually make this set unique?

What are "well-known," or not well-known, restrictions that make the set of basis vectors (order does not matter) unique for some given finite dimensional vector space?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Set of basis vectors is never unique. You chose one that makes your live easier. Like, orthogonal or orthonormal, or aligned with some other vectors of interest.

Comment: You might want to consider Gram-Schmidt process, to find a unique orthonormal basis based on a given basis from the same space.

Comment: What I mean is that there are an infinite number of basis but by adding restrictions to these vectors, you narrow the number of sets that satisfy the restrictions. My question is if I can keep adding restrictions until I get a unique set of basis vectors. For example in $\mathbb{R}^1$, if I  add one restriction e.g. $||v||=1$ then the basis vector is unique... (I hope that makes things clearer)

Comment: @Kaster modified question to hopefully clarify my meaning.

Comment: Can you say what's the ultimate purpose of such restrictions? What the final goal?

Comment: @Kaster  I am dealing with an optimization problem and part of the problem requires a basis for a vector space. Now, it doesn't really matter what the basis vectors are just that they are unique (and that they are a basis). Think of a maximization problem and some of the parameters are these vectors. So I am looking for a way to add some restrictions so that the optimization finds a unique set of basis vectors (does not matter what they are) and other parameters.

Comment: If it doesn't matter what they are, just pick one and be done with it. Regardless, if it's optimization problem, or any other problem involving vectors, your final answer won't depend on the basis you choose.

Comment: @Kaster. Okay thanks. I did something like that.... from what I understand it seems then that there is no way to say something like there is a  unique basis in every vector space that is orthonormal and satisfies (i), (ii) and (iii)...

Answer (score 2):

If $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ form a basis for $V$, it is easy to show that $\{av_1,...,av_n\}$ is a basis for $V$ unless $a=0$. Then, uniqueness of basis is equivalent to $V=\{0\}$, the trivial vector space (but in this case, Would you consider 0 is a basis?)

Comment: Okay, but what if I restrict $||v_1||=1$ then if you multiply by $a$ then $a$ must equal $1$.

Comment: $\|v_1\|=1$ doesn't implies uniqueness for basis: it's enough "play" with the other $n-1$ vectors.

Comment: Okay, but can I keep adding restrictions until the set of basis vectors is unique?

Comment: Trivially if you impose $n=dim(V)$ restrictions you can stay uniqueness: "I want $v_1=$vector explicitely and  $v_2=$vector explicitely and... $v_n=$vector explicitely" wherever $v_1,...,v_n$ be linearly independent

Comment: Indeed, the only non trivial restriction would be ordenered basis, cause if $\beta$ is a basis, any permutation of $\beta$ is also.

Comment: I don't want to explicitly list the vectors. I want to impose conditions like $||v_1||=1$, $||v_2||=1$ etc.... I think you are imposing more than $dim(V)$ restrictions when you explicitly list the vectors.

Comment: Yes, I mean a unique set (i.e. up to order).. clarified this in the question.